# Как исключить выходящие за пределы матрицы данные

Tags: golang

Необходимо написать функцию, которая для элемента возвращает всех его соседей. Диагональные элементы соседями не считаются.

В целом задача решена, но в случае если элементы выходят за пределы матрицы, то компилятор выдает ошибку `runtime error: index out of range [-1]` . Теперь я думаю сделать условие, которое исключает выходящие за пределы матрицы данные. Подскажите как будет выглядеть такое условие? Я уже пытался сделать что то вроде: если элемент = -1, то удалить элемент из ответа. Но не работает.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Input(y, x int) []int {
    matrix := [][]int{
        []int{0, 2, 3},
        []int{2, 3, 1},
        []int{8, 7, 4},
        []int{3, 2, 1},
    }
    k := []int{matrix[y+1][x], matrix[y-1][x], matrix[y][x+1], matrix[y][x-1]}
    for _, z := range k {
        if z == -1 { //затык здесь
            return append(k[z:], k[:z-1]...)
        }
    }
    return k
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(Input(0, 0))
}
```

То есть для данного случая должен получиться ответ [2, 2]

Comment: ошибка возникает в строчке с ``k :=``, а не в той, где указано. В других языках для таких случаев существуют исключения, но в голанге их нет, насколько мне известно. Так что можно или просто вручную проверять, не выходит ли какой-то из индексов за пределы существующих, или узнать, как работают с исключениями в голанге и применить на практике.

Comment: Дело в том, что если задать функции Input координаты, например,  (1,1) то код работает и ошибок не возникает. Значит k работает. Но если результат выполнения функции выходит за рамки матрицы возникает эта ошибка. Вы правы, в Go нет исключений, для этих целей используют тип error, но как его использовать в данном случае я пока не знаю

Comment: Как раз нет. Если у вас работает, только когда "если", то это значит, что не работает. А у вас ошибка в присвоении значений переменной k, если индекс выходит за пределы. Именно это вам и надо обработать. Можно даже просто тупо написать, что для случая "х или y равно 0" и для случая "x или y равно максимальный индекс" брать только существующие элементы, не выходя за границы.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Кстати, если интересно, более подробный ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225886/how-to-exclude-coordinates-which-overflow-matrix/72226348#72226348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это задачка просто на аккуратно проверить граничные случаи

```
func GrabNeigh(y, x int) ([]int, error) {
    matrix := [][]int{
        {0, 2, 3},
        {2, 3, 1},
        {8, 7, 4},
        {3, 2, 1},
    }

    var res []int

    h := len(matrix) - 1    // примитивная валидация, полагая что высота > 0
    w := len(matrix[0]) - 1 // примитивная валидация, полагая что ширина > 0

    if y > h || x > w {
        return nil, errors.New("Out of range")
    }

    if y != 0 {
        res = append(res, matrix[y-1][x])
    }
    if x != 0 {
        res = append(res, matrix[y][x-1])
    }
    if y != h {
        res = append(res, matrix[y+1][x])
    }
    if x != w {
        res = append(res, matrix[y][x+1])
    }

    return res, nil
}
```